# Filtering query with Laravel's Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I've defined Eloquent models like this:

```php
class Order extends Eloquent {
    public function station() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Station');
    }
}

class Station extends Eloquent {
    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Client');
    }

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }
}

class Client extends Eloquent {
    public function stations() {
        return $this->hasMany('Station');
    }
}
```

Now I'm wanting to do a query that relates to all of them, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it the Eloquent way.  This is the SQL for the query I want to return:

```sql
SELECT o.id, c.name AS cname, s.name AS sname, o.created, o.due, o.name, o.comments, o.points
FROM orders o
JOIN station s ON o.station_id = s.id
JOIN client c ON c.id = s.client_id
WHERE s.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM orders WHERE complete
)
```

I'm confused on how I do that the Laravel/Eloquent way.

Comment: What result you need? Eloquent models or array of those `selected` fields? Also are you sure about this: `WHERE s.id IN ...` - isn't it `o.id IN...` ? You can build exactly the same query with `Query\Builder`, no raw pieces needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here you have several ways to handle it.

1. Executing the whole raw query
2. Making an eloquent query

To gain more control over the query I would got for the first point

this can be achieved by executing the statement directly

`DB::select(DB::raw($your_sql_here))`;

or by building with the query constructor.

The second way involves some research over how relations are working.
The final query might look like this (not exact, but will give you a hint):

```
Order::with('station.client')->whereIn('station.id', DB::raw('SELECT id FROM orders WHERE complete'))
```

Hope this will help. Also there is a great  [cheet-sheet](http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/)  that can provide you on more methods over DB and Model objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading):

```
$orders = Order::where('complete', $complete)->with('station.client')->get();
```

Then you can loop over each order:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {

    echo e("The order ID is $order->id <br>");
    echo e("The station ID is {$order->station->id} <br>");
    echo e("The client ID is {$order->station->client->id} <br>");
}
```

Hope that helps.